# How to connect 2 virtual machines(VMWare Workstation 7.0) in a separate network?

Tags: virtual-machine, vmware-workstation

There are supposed to be 2 networks: i) The first one is the one which all the virtual machines and the host share(Host-only condition). This one is easily achievable for me, as an amateurish beginner. ii)The second network is the one in which only 2 virtual machines are to be connected. These 2 virtual machines should also be connected to the Network(i).

I understand that for the 2 virtual hosts that are to be connected in a separate networks simultaneously, it means that they need to have 2 IPs, and hence 2 ports(physical)/ethernet interfaces?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VMWare calls them Lan Segments.

> **Configuring LAN Segments**
>
> A LAN segment is a private network that is shared by other virtual
>   machines. A LAN segment can be useful for multitier testing, network
>   performance analysis, and situations where virtual machine isolation
>   are important.

For Workstation 9 it is in the help `Using VMWare Workstation` under the topic `Configuring Network Connections`.

Comment: Lan segments looks like for isolate two guests on same host. Isn't it ?

Comment: follow this [link](http://pubs.vmware.com/workstation-11/topic/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-DEE1E2F1-5DA4-4C83-B7C5-A1165C84C757.html?resultof=%22%6c%61%6e%22%20%22%73%65%67%6d%65%6e%74%22%20) to the VMware documentation

Answer (score 1):

You can install vpn on host machines, and add the guests to it, vpn solutions are:

openvpn, pptp (native windows), ipsec, may be some other.